# How to set the font size and Font Awesome Icons on same height

Tags: html, css, css-position, font-awesome, font-size

1) All the elements in the first div have font-size 16px. But it looks like the Facebook icon is taller than the twitter icon. How can I make it, that it has same height?

[image: Facebook Icon taller than Twitter Icon]

2) The Facebook icon in the second div look like it is taller than the font-size and the Twitter icon looks like it is smaller than the font-size. How can I change the height of the icons, that they have the same height like the font-size?

**Or know someone an alternative to font-awesome where all icons have same height?**

Here's my current code **(YOU SHOULD CLICK ON "Run Code Snippet" -> "FULL PAGE"):**

```css
/* ########################################################################## */
/* Global Settings */
/* ########################################################################## */

html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* ########################################################################## */
/* Clearfix-Hack */
/* ########################################################################## */

.clearfix::after{
 content:"";
 clear:both;
 display: block;
}

/* ########################################################################## */
/* Entire Page */
/* ########################################################################## */

.entire-page{
  margin: 0 15%;
}


/* ########################################################################## */
/*  Menu */
/*  ########################################################################## */

.container{
  width:100;
  text-align:center;
}

nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;

}

nav li{
 float: left;
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 30px 30px;
}

.group2{
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.group2 .fa-facebook,
.group2 .fa-twitter{
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:16px;
  vertical-align:baseline;
}

.social-icons:hover{
  color:#E95D0F;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="entire-page">

    <!-- ########################################################################## -->
    <!--  Menu -->
    <!--  ########################################################################## -->
    <nav>
      <ul>

        <div class="container">

          <div class="group1">
            <li><a class="social-icons" href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a class="social-icons" href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> Twitter</a></li>
          </div>

          <div class="group2">
            <li><a class="social-icons" href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a class="social-icons" href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> Twitter</a></li>
          </div>

          

        </div>

      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `font-size`, `line-height` w/ `vertical-align` on the icon element(s)

Comment: Your Facebook icon is no taller than your Twitter icon; it's a trick of the eye :)

Comment: @Ron Royston which values should I choose for font-size, line-height and vertical-align if I have a font-size of 16px for my text?

Comment: @Obsidian Age I've edited my answer and added a image where you can see, that they have different sizes.

Comment: @RonRoyston I've now edited my code but it is still not working. What should I change? .group2 .fa-facebook,
.group2 .fa-twitter{
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:16px;
  vertical-align:baseline;
}

Comment: Give the `.fa` class a background color, then you will see that those elements are the same size. The icons themselves are simply of different “sizes”, the Twitter one has space on top and bottom, whereas the Facebook one does not. If you want them to be “the same size”, then you will have to modify the font-size for either one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

put them in one `div` with single font-size style.

Modify your **`.group3`** selector in CSS file, just like following

```
.group3 {
   font-size:30px;
}
```

Facebook and Twitter icon height are set by design

Answer (score -1):

You can use `fa-fw` class to fix size and prevent this issue.

For example:
`fa fa-fw fa-facebook`

This works for Font Awesome 4.7 and 5

More examples: 
https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/